# PHP Warning "Warning: ob_start(): function '' not found or invalid function name" in Symfony 1?

Tags: php, symfony1

Why am I getting:

> Warning: ob_start(): function '' not found or invalid function name in /symfony-1.3\lib\config\sfApplicationConfiguration.class.php on line 155

This occurs with Symfony 1.x projects. I am using Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4.1.

The mentioned line has:

```
ob_start(sfConfig::get('sf_compressed') ? 'ob_gzhandler' : '');
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Try using a `null` value instead of the empty string.

```
ob_start(sfConfig::get('sf_compressed') ? 'ob_gzhandler' : null);
```

Comment: Interestingly this bug is in Symfony framework :) well I guess I can edit the file locally :P

Comment: is this change backward compatible? does it still work for php 5.2?

Comment: Hesky, I can't find any changes of this parameter in the PHP manual for [ob_start](http://php.net/ob_start). On the other hand, PHP 5.2 reached end of life 3 years ago so there have been lots of time to move all code bases to a newer version. Anyone still running PHP 5.2 in production must have a really hard time manually porting security patches, so adding a NULL option to ob_start manually should be pretty easy.

Comment: This bug got fixed in symfony version 1.4.20

Comment: This fixed the issue in Symfony version 1.0.11 I had to update the code in {PEAR directory}/symfony/symfony.php To find your {PEAR directory}, run `pear config-show | grep "PEAR directory"`

Comment: @EmilVikström : It fixed my problem but I didn't understand what happened here. Can I know the reason why we did it and what was the problem with previous one.

Answer (score 3):

-`ob_start(sfConfig::get('sf_compressed') ? 'ob_gzhandler' : '');`

+`ob_start(sfConfig::get('sf_compressed') ? 'ob_gzhandler' : null);`

Answer (score 0):

### This was fixed in symfony 1.4.16

See [symfony 1.4.16 changelog](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/blob/v1.4.16/CHANGELOG):

> - [...]
> - [33214] fixed ob_start() behavior on CLI (closes #9970)
> - [33208] fixed ob_start usage (to avoid warning in PHP 5.4, closes #9970)

So simply make sure to use at least that version.

**Preferably use the latest/last/final symfony 1.x version released, which is 1.4.20.**

You can grab them at [the official Git mirror for symfony 1.x](https://github.com/symfony/symfony1/releases) .