# Upgrade PHP to 5.4 Symfony errors

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, upgrade

I've searched and didn't find answer so…

I try to upgrade from PHP 5.3 to PHP 5.4.24. The upgrade itself went well, but now I have problem with my Symfony (ver. 1.3.5-DEV) project. I try to rebuild the project and get errors:
ob_start(): function '' not found or invalid function name in PHP Warning:  ob_start(): function '' not found or invalid function name in /var/www/html/myproject/lib/vendor/symfony13/config/sfApplicationConfiguration.class.php on line 155

I'be grateful for any advises

Comment: the symfony configuration class runs into an unknown function apparently. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380932/php-warning-warning-ob-start-function-not-found-or-invalid-function-name

Comment: You can also take a look at this fork of [symfony1](https://github.com/LExpress/symfony1) which add support for php 5.4+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you assigned the [first param of the functions](http://php.net/ob_start) an empty string `''` instead of `null` as supposed in the param signature:

```
bool ob_start ([ callback $output_callback = NULL [ ... ] ] )
```

Warnings **are not** errors. Your script execution won't stop.

If you need further help, please show the relevant code, line 150 - 160.

If you want to disable the warnings, notices and strict messages:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_WARNING);
```

on top of your bootstrapping script / index.

Comment: Thanks! It's part of vendor's code so I thought it supposed to be like that… ;-) But… now I have another thing:  >> propel    Running "om" phing task
PHP Strict standards:  Declaration of UnixFileSystem::getBooleanAttributes() should be compatible with FileSystem::getBooleanAttributes($f) in /var/www/html/lms542.ioki.com.pl/lib/vendor/symfony13/plugins/sfPropelPlugin/lib/vendor/phing/system/io/UnixFileSystem.php on line 278 . I cannot put any line of code, because it's end of the class..

Comment: Maybe symfony isn't into standards.. or is your version not compatible with 5.4 ? "strict standards" is not an error either.

Comment: I've read I need to update Phing classes. Maybe this will help. Anyway - thanks for your help.